Dynamic shortcuts in AppShortcutsProvider

First button (New Board) is implemented like this:
struct MyShortcutsProvider: AppShortcutsProvider {
       
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        AppShortcut(
            intent: MyIntent(),
            phrases: [
                «phrase»,
            ],
            shortTitle: «New Board»,
            systemImageName: «plus»
        )
    }


How to dynamically add other buttons? For example, the user created folders in the application. and I want to make it possible to go to these folders from spotlight search
Tried things like that
struct MyShortcutsProvider: AppShortcutsProvider {
       
    static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
        return MyShortcutsProvider().createShortcuts()
    }

    func createShortcuts() -> [AppShortcut] {
        var appShortcuts2: [AppShortcut] = []

         for item in 0..<3 {
            appShortcuts2.append(
                AppShortcut(
                    intent: MyIntent(),
                    phrases: [
                        "Open \(.applicationName)",
                    ],
                    shortTitle: "\(item)",
                    systemImageName: "circle"
                )
            )
        }
        return appShortcuts2
    }


}


In this case the "Top Hit" is not a list of all the shortcuts available. Rather than a best prediction from the search being made.
I guess what you could do is have different shortcuts such as the code you provided, but this would not guaranteed that you would see them in spotlight. You should see them on the Shortcuts App in your app section.
